# Incomplete python text colour in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, colors, reset

I am programming with Visual Studio Code a python code but one month after installing VS the colours of the python code have changed

I have tried uninstalling python and reinstalling it, but to no avail.
I did the same thing with Visual Studio and also the same result.
I have also removed all the extensions I had but the [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Rh7.png) persists

What I would like to have is like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIbjU.jpg) taken from the internet,  where words have several different colours

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the theme in VSCode can also change how syntax is highlighted. You can test this by changing the theme to something else:

- Open the command palette (ctrl+shift+p)
- Type "color theme" and press enter
- Choose a different theme from the list e.g. the default (Dark+/Light+) if it isn't already selected